# Set defaults for matplotlib methods

Tags: matplotlib

I'm doing some image processing in which I have to call `imshow()` often. However, the default colormap and attributes don't work for me so I have to do:

```
gray()
imshow(myImage, interpolation='none', origin='lower')
```

How to set the value of `imshow` to have default `interpolation='none', origin='lower'` so it could be called just with `imshow(myImage)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is that the atributes of `imshow()` are actually atributes of the `matplotlib.image`. And can be set it matplotlibrc in the *image* part.

Or dynamically with

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('image', interpolation='none', origin='lower', cmap = 'gray')
```

Reference from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)